# How to create dynamic a-tag onclick to call external function using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm working on laravel project with ajax request. I can have response from controller as below.

```
    success:function(response){
         var output = "";
         $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            var room = item.room;
            var route = `{{url('medicalroom/callque/${id}')}}`;                    
            output += `<a onclick="confirmation(event)" href="${route}" '>Room ${("00" + room).slice(-2)} </a>`;
            })
         $('#roomlist').html(output);
     }

    function confirmation(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(route);
    });
```

I can add results to div `roomlist` but once do the `onclick` then not event fire. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. For me it is working

Comment: Please add more code to findout the exact issue

Comment: Dear Abana Clara, meant I  would like to create A-TAG with the onclick event inside object array loop.

Comment: Your code is indented; is there an encapsulating function around `confirmation()`? If so, `window.confirmation()` is probably `undefined`; do you have a `ReferenceError` in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this, don't add the call to onclick, instead use some class and then get the route from the href of the link or you can store it on a `data-route=${route}` attribute and get it like `$(this).data('route')`

```js
  $(function(){
  
  function func(response) {
         var output = "";
         $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            var room = item.room;
            var route = `medicalroom/callque/4`;                    
            output += `<a class='link' href="${route}" '>Room ${("00" + room).slice(-2)} </a>`;
            })
         $('#roomlist').html(output);
     }
 
 var resp = [{room: '001'}, {room: '002'}, {room: '003'}, {room: '004'}, {room: '005'}];
     
     func(resp)
     
     $(document).on('click', '.link', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
        alert(this.href);
     })
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="roomlist"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#roomlist').html(output);
```

You can try the `append()` or `attr()` in ajax to add the attribute in a input type or a href tag .

Try this .
Create an ID to a href tag

```
<a href = "#" id = "hello1">
```

In ajax response ,

```
$('#hello1').attr('onclick','confirmation(event)');
```

add another function (confirmation) for onclick event and do the other things in that function .

Comment: Dear farooq. Yes, with related way.